# Is this the correct implementation of a `makefile` in C?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm working on a project and I need to create a `makefile` for it.

Here are the files and the conventions that I need to follow:

- program5.c //Driver Code
- List item
- data.h
- list.c/.h
- profile.c/.h (provided)
- queue.c/.h
- stack.c/.h
- vector.c/.h
- makefile

You must have the following labels in your makefile:

- all - to compile all your code to an executable called ‘program4’ (no extension). Do not run.
- run - to compile if necessary and run
- memcheck - to compile only if necessary and run with Valgrind
- clean - to remove all executables and object files

all: program5

```
program5: program5.o stack.o queue.o vector.o list.o profile.o
    gcc -g program5.o stack.o queue.o vector.o list.o profile.o -o program5

program5.o: program5.c stack.h queue.h vector.h list.h profile.h
    gcc -g -c program5.c -o program5.o

stack.o: stack.c stack.h
    gcc -g -c stack.c -o stack.o

queue.o: queue.c queue.h
    gcc -g -c queue.c -o queue.o

vector.o: vector.c vector.h
    gcc -g -c vector.c -o vector.o

list.o: list.c list.h
    gcc -g -c list.c -o list.o

profile.o: profile.c profile.h
    gcc -g -c profile.c -o profile.o

run: all
    ./program5

memcheck: all
    valgrind -v ./program5

clean:
    rm -f *.o program5
```

This is what my `makefile` looks like for the following imports that I need to make in my `program5.c` file. I want to know if what I wrote in the `makefile` is correct or not?

For example, the `program5` and `program5.o` part, are they correct or should I break them up more or something else.

```
#include "stack.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "profile.h"
#include "profile.h"
```

Comment: So..Does it work?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm still writing the code for few of the files, so can't say if the code is working or not. I just need to know if the syntax for my `makefile` is correct or not.

Comment: You don't need the code to be working. You need it to compile to know the makefile is working.

Comment: Just ran the `makefile`, gave me tons of errors for the files I haven't finished yet. So, does that mean that the `makefile` is correctly working? Haven't used makefile that much.

Comment: Put some dummy data in the files you haven't finished yet, enough to make them compile, then run `make`.  That should tell you if you're missing anything.  That said, I don't see any glaring issues with it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The criteria for correctness of a makefile are much more than simply that it compiles a file.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But this is really the first indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your `makefile` works, but note that you don't need all those `-o`

```
gcc -g -c vector.c -o vector.o
```

should be

```
gcc -g -c vector.c
```

anyway you can improve it using some directives:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g
OBJECTS = program5.o stack.o queue.o vector.o list.o profile.o

all: program5

program5: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o program5

program5.o: program5.c stack.h queue.h vector.h list.h profile.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c program5.c

stack.o: stack.c stack.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c stack.c

queue.o: queue.c queue.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c queue.c

vector.o: vector.c vector.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c vector.c

list.o: list.c list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c list.c

profile.o: profile.c profile.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c profile.c

run: all
    ./program5

memcheck: all
    valgrind -v ./program5

clean:
    rm -f *.o program5
```

And it's a good idea to compile with warnings:

```
CFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -W -g
```

instead of

```
CFLAGS = -g
```

Answer (score 2):

First, go read the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents).  Reading the primary documentation is better than guessing.

I don't see anything *obviously* wrong, but you can certainly simplify it quite a bit.

GNU make allows you to use a variety of *implicit rules*, rather that write an explicit rule for every target.  For example, `make` already provides an implicit rule to compile any `*.c` file to a `*.o`:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The automatic variable `$<` corresponds to the prerequisite (right hand side of the `:`), and the variable `$@` corresponds to the target.  `CC`, `CFLAGS`, and `CPPFLAGS` are predefined variable names used by implicit rules - you just set them to the values you want to use:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror
```

So, one way to simplify this would be

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror
SRCS = program5.c stack.c queue.c vector.c list.c profile.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

TARGET=program5

##
## rebuild the target if any of the object files are newer
##
$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

all : $(TARGET)

run : all
        ./$(TARGET)

memcheck: all
        valgrind -v $(TARGET)

clean:
        rm -rf $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

Note that there's no need to write any rules for the separate `.o` files - again, GNU Make already provides that rule.  You just need to set `CC`, `CFLAGS`, and `CPPFLAGS` appropriately.

Now, one thing this makefile does *not* do is check for dependencies on the header (.h) files.  You can override the implicit rule by adding something like the following:

```
%.o : %.c %.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This will rebuild *file*.o if either *file*.c or *file*.h are newer.  But sometimes multiple .c files include the same .h file, so you may need to trigger multiple builds if a single header changes.

gcc has an option to generate a list of Makefile rules.  For example, if `program5.c` includes all of the above headers, then `gcc -MM program5.c` will generate the output

```
program5.o : program5.c list.h profile.h queue.h stack.h vector.h
```

You can write this output to a file, then include that file in the main Makefile.  Here's an example from the GNU make manual linked above:

```
##
## For each source file, create a .d file that explicitly lists the header
## dependencies.  
##
%.d : %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@; \
        $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
        sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
        rm -rf $@.$$$$
```

Then after your `clean` target you'd add

```
include $(SRCS:.c=.d)
```

to include the generated .d files.

**EDIT**

Here's a working example (mainly for me to make sure I wasn't lying to you).  I generated a set of .c and .h files:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: ls
total 56
drwxrwxr-x   2 fbgo448 users  4096 2018-12-07 09:28 .
drwxrwxr-x 163 fbgo448 users 16384 2018-12-07 09:11 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    52 2018-12-07 09:25 data.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    83 2018-12-07 09:12 list.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    58 2018-12-07 09:12 list.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users   512 2018-12-07 09:28 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    93 2018-12-07 09:14 profile.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    67 2018-12-07 09:13 profile.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users   264 2018-12-07 09:24 program5.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    86 2018-12-07 09:14 queue.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    62 2018-12-07 09:14 queue.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    87 2018-12-07 09:15 stack.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    62 2018-12-07 09:15 stack.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    89 2018-12-07 09:16 vector.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    65 2018-12-07 09:16 vector.h
```

These are pretty simplistic - they just define a single function that prints the name of the module, like so:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: more stack.*
::::::::::::::
stack.c
::::::::::::::
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

void stack( void )
{
  printf( "stack\n" );
}

::::::::::::::
stack.h
::::::::::::::
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

void stack( void );

#endif
```

except for `program5`, which calls the others:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: more program5.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "data.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "profile.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include "vector.h"

int main( void )
{
  printf( "g_data = %d\n", g_data ); // defined in data.h
  list();
  profile();
  queue();
  stack();
  vector();

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror
CPPFLAGS=

SRCS=program5.c list.c profile.c queue.c stack.c vector.c

##
## The following lines are examples of pattern substitions - the SRCS
## variable will be expanded, and each _file_.c will be replaced with
## a _file_.o for OBJS and _file_.d for DEPS.
##
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)
DEPS=$(SRCS:.c=.d)

TARGET=program5

##
## Build the dependency files
##
%.d : %.c
        set -e; rm -rf $@; \
        $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
        sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : , g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
        rm -rf $@.$$$$

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

all: $(TARGET)

run: all
        ./$(TARGET)

memcheck: all
        valgrind -v $(TARGET)

clean:
        rm -rf $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

##
## The '-' in front of the include directive will suppress a warning
## if any of the .d files cannot be found.  This will be the case the
## first time you run the makefile, or after running a 'make clean'.
##
-include $(DEPS)
```

Here's the result of running `make run`:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: make run
set -e; rm -rf vector.d; \
gcc -MM  vector.c > vector.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(vector\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o vector.d : , g' < vector.d.$$ > vector.d; \
rm -rf vector.d.$$
set -e; rm -rf stack.d; \
gcc -MM  stack.c > stack.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(stack\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o stack.d : , g' < stack.d.$$ > stack.d; \
rm -rf stack.d.$$
set -e; rm -rf queue.d; \
gcc -MM  queue.c > queue.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(queue\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o queue.d : , g' < queue.d.$$ > queue.d; \
rm -rf queue.d.$$
set -e; rm -rf profile.d; \
gcc -MM  profile.c > profile.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(profile\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o profile.d : , g' < profile.d.$$ > profile.d; \
rm -rf profile.d.$$
set -e; rm -rf list.d; \
gcc -MM  list.c > list.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(list\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o list.d : , g' < list.d.$$ > list.d; \
rm -rf list.d.$$
set -e; rm -rf program5.d; \
gcc -MM  program5.c > program5.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(program5\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o program5.d : , g' < program5.d.$$ > program5.d; \
rm -rf program5.d.$$
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o program5.o program5.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o list.o list.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o profile.o profile.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o queue.o queue.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o stack.o stack.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o vector.o vector.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    program5.o list.o profile.o queue.o stack.o vector.o -o program5
./program5
g_data = 0
list
profile
queue
stack
vector
```

Here's a listing with the generated .d and .o files:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: ls
total 96
drwxrwxr-x   2 fbgo448 users  4096 2018-12-07 09:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 163 fbgo448 users 16384 2018-12-07 09:11 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    52 2018-12-07 09:25 data.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    83 2018-12-07 09:12 list.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    30 2018-12-07 09:50 list.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    58 2018-12-07 09:12 list.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users  1480 2018-12-07 09:50 list.o
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users   974 2018-12-07 09:48 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    93 2018-12-07 09:14 profile.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    42 2018-12-07 09:50 profile.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    67 2018-12-07 09:13 profile.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users  1480 2018-12-07 09:50 profile.o
-rwxrwxr-x   1 fbgo448 users 10070 2018-12-07 09:50 program5
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users   264 2018-12-07 09:24 program5.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    84 2018-12-07 09:50 program5.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users  1864 2018-12-07 09:50 program5.o
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    86 2018-12-07 09:14 queue.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    34 2018-12-07 09:50 queue.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    62 2018-12-07 09:14 queue.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users  1480 2018-12-07 09:50 queue.o
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    87 2018-12-07 09:15 stack.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    34 2018-12-07 09:50 stack.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    62 2018-12-07 09:15 stack.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users  1480 2018-12-07 09:50 stack.o
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    89 2018-12-07 09:16 vector.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    38 2018-12-07 09:50 vector.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    65 2018-12-07 09:16 vector.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users  1480 2018-12-07 09:50 vector.o
```

`make clean` will get rid of all the generated files:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: make clean
rm -rf program5 program5.o list.o profile.o queue.o stack.o vector.o program5.d list.d profile.d queue.d stack.d vector.d
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: ls
total 56
drwxrwxr-x   2 fbgo448 users  4096 2018-12-07 09:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 163 fbgo448 users 16384 2018-12-07 09:11 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    52 2018-12-07 09:25 data.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    83 2018-12-07 09:12 list.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    58 2018-12-07 09:12 list.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users   974 2018-12-07 09:48 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    93 2018-12-07 09:14 profile.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    67 2018-12-07 09:13 profile.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users   264 2018-12-07 09:24 program5.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    86 2018-12-07 09:14 queue.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    62 2018-12-07 09:14 queue.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    87 2018-12-07 09:15 stack.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    62 2018-12-07 09:15 stack.h
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    89 2018-12-07 09:16 vector.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 fbgo448 users    65 2018-12-07 09:16 vector.h
```

Thanks to the automatically generated dependencies, if I update`data.h`, that should trigger a build of `program5.c`:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: touch data.h
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: make
set -e; rm -rf program5.d; \
gcc -MM  program5.c > program5.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(program5\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o program5.d : , g' < program5.d.$$ > program5.d; \
rm -rf program5.d.$$
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o program5.o program5.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    program5.o list.o profile.o queue.o stack.o vector.o -o program5
```

Similarly, if I update `stack.h`, that should trigger a rebuild of `stack.c` and `program5.c`:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: touch stack.h
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/make: make
set -e; rm -rf stack.d; \
gcc -MM  stack.c > stack.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(stack\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o stack.d : , g' < stack.d.$$ > stack.d; \
rm -rf stack.d.$$
set -e; rm -rf program5.d; \
gcc -MM  program5.c > program5.d.$$; \
sed 's,\(program5\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o program5.d : , g' < program5.d.$$ > program5.d; \
rm -rf program5.d.$$
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o program5.o program5.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    -c -o stack.o stack.c
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    program5.o list.o profile.o queue.o stack.o vector.o -o program5
```

Hope this helps.  Again, dig into the make manual I linked above, you can do some really cool stuff with it.

Comment: Nice mini-tutorial! That's why I love SO

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts! I really appreciate it. I see the value and power of `makefile`.